# How to save the results from ls to a command?

Tags: shell, make

I want the results from an ls to be saved in a var inside a makefile
the command is simply the following:

```
ls text*
```

and the result suppose to be something like : text1.txt
What i put in my script is:

```
text = some commands to fetch the "text" .
com = `ls $(text)*`
```

What is actually saved at $com is the results of the entire ls without the $(text)* parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, Pure posix make doesn't allow that. You'll need to resort to some kind of extension provided by the precise version of make you are using.  For example with GNU make

> com=$(wildcard $(text)*)

or nearer to what you are asking, but launch an additional shell

> com=$(shell ls $(text)*)

Comment: @Iraklis Use `com=$(wildcard $(text)*)`. Calling `ls` here has no benefit and might occasionally cause trouble. Also, note that a variable is expanded each time it is used; this might make a difference if you use `$(com)` inside a command that creates some files that would match. If you want the value to be computed when the variable is defined, use `com := $(wildcard $(text)*)`.